# Convert string with Unicode to show unicode in java?

Tags: java, string, unicode

I am trying to convert strings that contain a unicode to the actual character but everything I have found so far either only work if the string is only the unicode or converts the symbol to the code.

This is the string I am using as an example right now

```
Rebroadcast of Shows from the past Week! RPGs, Talk shows, Science, Wisdom, Vampires and more - Good stuff! \\u003c3 - !rbschedule for more info
```

I am getting this in from an API call so I can't just write it as \ instead of the \\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\\
```

That is called *escaping*, and it is what is currently blocking you from seeing the `<` character.
Un-escaping is **not** what you'd actually want **to do manually**, as there are many caveats.

You might want to use Apache `common-text` `StringEscapeUtils#unescapeJava`

```
final String result = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(yourString);
```

That will output *"...Good stuff! <3 - !rbschedule for more info..."*

---

The Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Or for Gradle

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.6'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

what if you replace all "//" with "/" dynamically?